# How can I check if static file exists or not from url_for() in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Is there is way I can check the static file from `url_for()` is really exist or not? Because I would like to check that if the first file does not exists, I would like to replace it with another file just like this in my html file:

```
{% set IconPng = url_for('static', filename="images/favo.png") %}
{% set IconIco = url_for('static', filename="images/favo.ico") %}
{% set Default = url_for('static', filename="images/default.ico") %}

{% if IconPng %}
    <img src="{{IconPng}}" />
{% elif IconIco %}
    <img src="{{IconIco}}" />
{% else %}
    <img src="{{Default}}" />
{% endif %}
```

I have tried with above and also with `or` operator like:

```
<img src="{{IconPng or IconIco or Default}}" />
```

However, it does not work. Any tip how can I do this check for `url_for()` in Flask?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it is rather task for javascript than your backend.
You can check if image exist using function like this one, and then change image src accordingly:

```
function file_exists(url){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. get path to static or template folder
2. concatenate with file name
3. check if file exist

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
import os
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    app.logger.debug(os.path.exists(os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'staticimage.png')))

    app.logger.debug(os.path.exists(os.path.join(app.template_folder, 'index.html')))
    return render_template('index.html')
```